# How to use wget with ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, wget, trustedconnection

I am using `wget` in my program to get some file using HTTP protocol. Here i need to set security so we moved **HTTP** protocol to **HTTPS**.

After changing to **HTTPS** how to perform `wget`. I mean how to make trusted connection between two machines then perform `wget`.

I want to make sure that `wget` can be performed from certain system only.

Answer (score 23):

## Step 1: SSL Certificates

First things first, if this machine is on the internet and the SSL certificate is signed by a trusted source, there is no need to specify a certificate.

However, if there is a self signed certificate involved things get a little more interesting.

For example:

- if this machine uses a self signed certificate, or
- if you are on a network with a proxy that re-encrypts all https connections

Then you need to trust the public key of the self signed certificate. You will need to export the public key as a `.CER` file. How you got the SSL certificate will determine how you get the [public key as a `.CER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28060160/3991654)

Once you have the `.CER` then...

## Step 2: Trust the Certificate

I suggest two options:

### option one

`wget --ca-certificate={the_cert_file_path}  https://www.google.com`

### option two

set the option on `~/.wgetrc`

```
ca_certificate={the_cert_file_path}
```

### Additional resources

- Blog post about this [wget and ssl certificates](http://lnotestoself.blogspot.com/2011/02/wget-and-ssl-certificates.html)
- [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html#Wgetrc-Commands)

Answer (score 6):

macOS users can use the `cert.pem` file:

```
wget --ca-certificate=/etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

or set in your `~/.wgetrc`:

```
ca_certificate = /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html#Wgetrc-Commands), if using a `~/.wgetrc` file, the setting is named `ca_certificate` (with an underscore), __not__ `ca-certificate` (with a hyphen)

Comment: @tony_tiger Oddly I think `ca-certificate` worked for me, but I'll edit the post since that's what's in the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (at least on my Debian and Ubuntu distributions), you can do the following to install your cert to be trusted system-wide.

Assuming your certificate is `~/tmp/foo.pem`, do the following:

Install the `ca-certificates` package, if it is not already present, then do the following to install `foo.pem`:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ chmod 444 foo.pem
$ sudo cp foo.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Once this is done, most apps (including wget, Python and others) should automatically use it when it is required by the remote site.

The only exception to this I've found has been the Firefox web browser.  It has its own private store of certificates, so you need to manually install the cert via its Settings interface if you require it there.

At least this has always worked for me (to install a corporate certificate needed for Internet access into the Linux VMs I create).