# How to extract the RSA public key from a .cer and store it in a .pem using OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, pem, cer

I have the requirement to extract the public key (RSA) from a `*.cer` file. I wish to extract the key and store it in a `.pem` file so I can use its value to encrypt values using [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt).

The following command converts a `.cer` to `.pem`:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Yet it doesn't generate a file with the public key but a file with the contents of the `*.cer` file.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICPDCCAamgAwIBAg............
*lots of extra contents*
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**What command should I use to extract the public key and store it in a `.pem` file?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Fighting with these things is often a developer's lot. There are a lot of questions on SO about certificate management. It's not Super User or Linux or Dev Ops, all of which aren't specific enough. I believe this is in fact the correct place.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Using this command I was able to generate the `.pem` with the contents of the public key.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -pubkey -noout > certificate_publickey.pem
```

Which produces:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCsM+whXrxmbCkPfkwY2EehYpIp
*blah blah blah blah*
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a correction: for a .cer file input, the `inform` parameter should be `der`

Comment: I was pretty sure that what I wrote in my answer was correct and did work for me... I did use `-inform pem`. Although if `-inform der` works too, then that's cool.

Comment: For anyone else trying this, `-inform DER` would not work for me, but `-inform PEM` works.

Comment: OMG I looked for this so long. This is mind blowing for me that instead of `-out` we should use `-noout` with redirection to file.
I tried to extract pub key from PEM file received from Google OAuth jwks_url v1 so now I finally did it. Thank you

Comment: Although the OP's intent is to use this with `jsencrypt` so his question was answered, it specifically asks about an RSA (PKCS#1) public key, but this answer appears to offer a PKCS#8 formatted public key.  Is the OP's original question possible?  The difference is the RSA public keys start with `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` as opposed to the PKCS#8 which start with `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY`.  If I can find the answer on my own, I will supply it as an alternate solution.

Comment: The solution to my question (RSA format, per OP's original request) is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930720/3196753

Answer (score 3):

Solution for PowerShell:

```
$certFile = "[path to .cer file]"
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFile)
$cer.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString($false)
```

Solution from C#:

```
string certificate = @"<PATH TO .CER>"; 
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate); 
string xml = cert.GetRSAPublicKey().ToXmlString(false);
```